# Selenium Desired Capabilities - set handlesAlerts for PhantomJS driver

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying out phantomJS with webdriver and I'm having trouble with handling javascript alerts.  I notice the phantomjs driver desired_capabilities has a field `'handlesAlerts': False`  Is there a way to set this value to true?  I've tried the obvious way but that doesn't have any effect:

```
drv = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities={'handlesAlerts': True})

print drv.desired_capabilities

{u'browserName': u'phantomjs',
 u'driverName': u'ghostdriver',
 u'driverVersion': u'1.0.3',
 u'handlesAlerts': False,
 u'javascriptEnabled': True,...}
```

I can change the value in the dictionary `drv.desired_capabilities['handlesAlerts'] = True`, but when I try to switch to an alert, I get an error message.

```
$cat index.html 
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('FOO!');
</script>
    Hello World.
</body>
</html>

>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.desired_capabilities['handlesAlerts'] = True
>>> driver.get('index.html')
>>> alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
>>> alert.text

Traceback (most recent call last):
<snip>
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 
   'Invalid Command Method -  Request    => 
                 {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json",
                              "Accept- Encoding":"identity",
                              "Connection":"close",
                              "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF- 8",
                              "Host":"127.0.0.1:56009", 
                              "User-Agent":"Python- urllib/2.7"},
                  "httpVersion":"1.1",
                  "method":"GET",
                  "url":"/alert_text",
                  "urlParsed": {"anchor":"",
                                "query":"",
                                "file":"alert_text",
                                "directory":"/",
                                "path":"/alert_text",
                                "relative":"/ alert_text",
                                "port":"",
                                "host":"",
                                "password":"",
                                "user":"",
                                "userInfo":"",
                                "authority":"",
                                "protocol ":"",
                                "source":"/alert_text",
                                "queryKey":{},
                                "chunks":["alert_text"]},
                                "urlOriginal":"/session/cd31ed90-a5f8-11e2-856d-5783db9f5342/alert_text"}'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The API specifies that desired capabilities be passed into the constructor. However, it may be the case that a driver does not support a feature requested in the desired capabilities. In that case, no error is thrown by the driver, and this is intentional. A capabilities object is returned by the session which indicates the capabilities that the session actually supports.

That is what's actually happening in this case. The PhantomJS driver doesn't support handling alerts as seen in [the source code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/056aa50c19b31de967ec7c30e59c6cb16680e48d/src/ghostdriver/session.js), the returned capabilities object indicates as much. In most language bindings, this returned capabilities object is read-only; in language bindings where the returned object may be read-write, modifying these capabilities has no actual effect on the session. In the pending [W3C WebDriver specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/), there is a `requiredCapabilities` setting which would throw an exception if the server cannot provide the capability, but that hasn't been implemented by any driver yet as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The wiki page is misleading. The API is actually implemented such that you pass in desired capabilities, and the remote end creates the session with what it's able to create. The remote end returns the capabilities actually available in the session, and that communication is one-way (local edits can't affect the remote session). In the pending [W3C WebDriver specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/), there is a `requiredCapabilities` setting which would throw an exception if the server cannot provide the capability, but that hasn't been implemented by any driver yet as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Downvoter, I don't see a point in downvoting correct answers even if you don't like the truth

Comment: @usmcs I'm sorry my attempt at humor got in the way and seemed like "snark". That was not the intention. I've rewritten the answer to better express the situation in the driver. Also note that the wiki page in question has been updated to be clearer regarding this situation. Other downvoters, this answer describes the way things are. Just because it's not what you want to hear, or it's not the way you want it to be doesn't make the answer any less valid or correct.