# web driver set capability for IE10 won't change the IE version?

Tags: java, webdriver

Since most of our clients still use ie8 and ie9, and we switched to Windows 8 OS, which comes with ie10 and due to requests from our clients, we need to test the software on ie8 version. I have a problem switching the ie version to 8, even though ie10 (amazingly) offers ie8 mode.

```
        System.setProperty(SeleniumProperties.ieDriver, SeleniumProperties.ieLocation);
        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = null;
        ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        ieCapabilities.setVersion("8");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
        System.out.println(((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities());
```

driver capabilities remain unchanged:

Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, elementScrollBehavior=0, javascriptEnabled=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=10, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, takesScreenshot=true}]

any kind of work around this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the browser emulation mode using the InternetExplorerDriver. It is simply not supported. Use a virtual machine with IE 8 installed.

Comment: thx Jim! are they working on implementation for the the future wd versions?

Comment: Who is "they"? The development team of IEDriverServer.exe? That would be (mostly) me, and the answer is "no." Using the "IE8-emulation-mode" of IE10 is only an approximation of testing on IE8. You're _far_ better off using a VM for this testing. As for why setting the version in the `DesiredCapabilities` object doesn't work, you can look at the accepted answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022226/selenium-desired-capabilities-set-handlesalerts-for-phantomjs-driver).