# Selenium: InternetExplorerDriver: disable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

How do I disabled JavaScript using the InternetExplorerDriver?

I have the following but it doesn't seem to disable JavaScript:

```
self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
   desired_capabilities={
       'platform': 'WINDOWS',
       'browserName': 'internet explorer',
       'version': '', 
       'javascriptEnabled': False})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable JavaScript in the IE driver. The `DesiredCapabilities` you request are not necessarily the capabilities of the created driver instance. That is, the driver does not throw an error if it does not support the capabilities you request; rather, it returns the actual capabilities the driver instance is using. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022226/selenium-desired-capabilities-set-handlesalerts-for-phantomjs-driver/) talks more about this particular detail of the WebDriver API.

Furthermore, much of the functionality of the IE driver (and indeed all drivers at present) is implemented in JavaScript. That means disabling JavaScript would render large parts of the IE driver (and indeed all drivers at present) useless.