# webdriver working with browser version

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the capabilities provided in webdriver and setting browser version. My chrome version is 32, but trying to run my test in chrome 30.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/drivers/win/chromedriver.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setCapability("version", "30");
    WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(caps);
    System.out.println(((RemoteWebDriver) wd).getCapabilities().getVersion());
```

When i print browser version its printing browser version as 32, but i set browser version as 30 in capabilities.
How can i use this capabilities in right way.

Comment: I am using chrome version 32.0.1700.107 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Since your tests run on a machine with Chrome 32, you can't set it Chrome 30, simply because you don't have Chrome 30.

WebDriver instance with `DesiredCapabilities` cannot be necessarily created even though the driver does not throw an error if it does not support the capabilities you request. This is how Selenium is designed.

For further information about `DesiredCapabilities`, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16022226/1177636). I quote JimEvans' answer:

> The API specifies that desired capabilities be passed into the
>   constructor. However, it may be the case that a driver does not
>   support a feature requested in the desired capabilities. In that case,
>   no error is thrown by the driver, and this is intentional. A
>   capabilities object is returned by the session which indicates the
>   capabilities that the session actually supports.
>
> That is what's actually happening in this case. The PhantomJS driver
>   doesn't support handling alerts, the returned capabilities object
>   indicates as much. In most language bindings, this returned
>   capabilities object is read-only; in language bindings where the
>   returned object may be read-write, modifying these capabilities has no
>   actual effect on the session. In the pending W3C WebDriver
>   specification, there is a requiredCapabilities setting which would
>   throw an exception if the server cannot provide the capability, but
>   that hasn't been implemented by any driver yet as far as I'm aware.